# Python BruteForce HelloWorld

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to Print Hello World bruteforcefully, I have seen this code and tried it and it works fine but when I try to make it dynamic it doesn't work.

```
import random
import sys
import time

targetArray = ["H",'e','l',"l","o"," ", "W", "o", "r","l","d" ]
stringArray = ["","","","","","","","","","",""]
i=0
count = 0
while i < len(targetArray):
    if stringArray[i] != targetArray[i]:
        stringArray[i] = chr(random.randint(0,256))

    if stringArray[i] == targetArray[i]:
        i += 1


    x = 0
    print("\n")
    while x< len(stringArray):
        print(stringArray[x]  , end = "" , flush = True)
        x += 1
        count += 1
    time.sleep(.01)

print("\nTotal Gusses is :",count)
```

But when I try to do it with String it goes on printing char infinitely.

```
import random
import sys
import time

targetString = "a"
string = []
i=0
x = 0
count = 0
print(len(targetString))
while string != targetString:
    for i in range(len(targetString)):
        string.append(chr(random.randint(32,126)))


    print("\n")
    while x< len(string):
        print(string[x]  , end = "")
        x += 1
        count += 1
    time.sleep(.01)

print("\nTotal Gusses is :",count)
```

How can I make it Dynamic?

credits - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Icoe6.jpg

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.. What do you mean by "dynamic", and what do you mean by brute force?

Comment: ``string`` is a *list* of strings whereas ``targetstring`` is just a string. The two will never compare equal, regardless of content.

Comment: @ResetACK I want it to work not only for hardcoded string but for an input value too, that a user will enter.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi First I took it as String only but I was facing the same problem then only, so I tried it with the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that you’re only initializing `string` and `x`
before the loop. So, it keeps adding characters to `string`, and
printing those new characters, but `string` keeps getting longer and
longer and will never match `targetString`.

The second problem is that `targetString` is of type `str` but `string`
is of type `list`, so of course they’ll never be equal.

The third problem is that we should not use `string` as an identifier,
because there is a standard library module named `string` and this would
shadow that name.

Not sure if this was intentional, but in the first program, you pick and
match characters one at a time (linear time), while in the second
program, you pick and match all of them at once (exponential time).
Actually, even worse than exponential: if `targetString` is length `N`
and you’re choosing from `M` characters (`M = 95` in the given code),
the complexity is `O(N * M ** N)`.

```
import random
#import sys    # not used
import time

targetString = list("a")
s = []
i = 0
x = 0
count = 0
print(len(targetString))
while s != targetString:
    s = []
    for i in range(len(targetString)):
        s.append(chr(random.randint(32,126)))
    print("")
    x = 0
    while x < len(s):
        print(s[x], end="")
        x += 1
        count += 1
    time.sleep(.01)

print("\nTotal Guesses is :",count)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But I still don't understand something like, 

1st - It stills check all the character at the same time instead of checking one character at a time as It does in the first case.


2nd - It Does work but it takes a lot of time as compared to the first one, how can I decrease its complexity?

Comment: Okay … I am going to guess that when you say “dynamic”, you mean “operating on a string entered at runtime” versus “operating on a hard-coded string”. If that is your intention, then just use the first program from your question, but input a string from the user, and convert it to a list of characters: `targetArray = list(userString)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the other problem is stringArray, how I update it's size too as accordingly to targetArray size?

Comment: `stringArray = [''] * len(targetArray)`